# Automate HTML form submission and save response page

Tags: forms, csv, automation, export-to-csv, silverstripe

I have a Silverstripe website, with a front end HTML form, that takes a postal code, uses Google API to determine which city this postal code belongs to and then displays information related to that city in HTML. This information is stored in the CMS mySQL database.
I want to automate the form submission to take a CSV file with a list of 1,200 postal codes and store the result of each on a downloadable item, could be Excel, a table PDF, CSV.. But I'm trying to avoid having someone entering the postal codes manually and copy/pasting the info into a an excel file.

I'm looking for advice on how to get started or what is the best approach.

Comment: There are a number of webdriver-based tools that allow for programmatic browser manipulation like you've described (e.g. selenium-webdriver, webdriver.io, watir-webdriver).  What language are you aiming to use?

Comment: My first though was JS but it could be PHP as well.

Comment: Check out http://webdriver.io/.  It should do the trick.

Comment: One way to do this in SilverStripe is to create a `Location` `DataObject` that has `PostalCode`, `City` and `Information` fields. Add a ModelAdmin to maintain the `Location` object. The ModelAdmin has a csv importer, which you can use to import all the postal codes. On your `PostalCode` class add an `onBeforeWrite` function that calls the Google API to fetch all the extra data. Then there is an export to csv button on the ModelAdmin. Instead of the `onBeoreWrite` step we could write a dev task to run the fetch over all the items.

Comment: Personally I'm questioning the feasibility of this. The question is can the mapping be exact, e.g. isn't there a possibility that the postcode shifts if the google can't map exactly your position on the edges of between two postcodes. Also the location where they are submitting the form might not be the one that they want to use for example from work. So you'd still need to be able to give them the possibility to edit the address information > thus making this as a nice to have feature but is it worth the coding time?